# Java Display.isCloseRequested() will not show true

Tags: java, lwjgl

I've just started using LWJGL and so this is an incredibly basic problem to run into but I've scoured the internet and can think of no solution. Also probably pertinent: I'm on a Mac.

Even when I press the x button, the method Display.isCloseRequested() refuses to return true. Below is the code for my entire "window" class, which is basically a shell for the display object.

```
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;


public class Window {
    public static void createWindow(int width, int height, String title){
        Display.setTitle(title);
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(width,height));
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
    public static void render(){
        Display.update();
    }
    public static boolean isCloseRequested(){
        System.out.println(Display.isCloseRequested());
        return Display.isCloseRequested();
    }
    public static int getWidth(){
        return Display.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
    }
    public static int getHeight(){
        return Display.getDisplayMode().getHeight();
    }
    public static String getTitle(){
        return Display.getTitle();
    }
}
```

This class is being referenced by a method in a main class, that looks like this:

```
private void run(){
        isRunning = true;
        while(isRunning){
            if (Window.isCloseRequested())
                stop();
            render();
        }
    }
```

The stop method is never being run, even when I click the x-button.

Comment: `System.out.println(Display.isCloseRequested());` - did you put this for troubleshooting? Subsequent call to `Display.isCloseRequested()` will (almost) always return false.

Answer (score 0):

Did some simple tutorials like http://ninjacave.com/lwjglbasics1 produce similar faulty behavior?

Important: i think there is also an reset of an intern Event which id caused through press the x Button, if you call the isCloseRequested twice.

So try to save the event and removed the syso-Line

Answer (score -1):

Is your aim to simply stop the `render()` process when the app window is closed?

If so, just add this to your main `JFrame` definition:

```
//replace frame with your main JFrame containing the X close button
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
        isRunning = false;
        frame.setVisible(false);
        frame.dispose();
    }
});
```

...and change your 2nd code to this:

```
private void run(){
    isRunning = true;
    while(isRunning){
        render();
    }
}
```

This way when you close your app main window the value of variable `isRunning` is changed to `false` and your `while()` loop will end terminating your `render()`.

In fact, I was dealing today exactly with this problem myself. I hit your post prior the solvement of my problem, but once I did solved it, I return here to post my solution (or at least the way it worked for me).

Surely, you have to make the same `isRunning` variable be available to both.

In fact I too never found out why that `isCloseRequested()` never change to `false` after I closed my app. Nevermind, this is my workaorund - hope it will work for you too.